Stripe Embedded Checkout Page Not Loading for First time on some devices
I am having a issue in my flask website.  I have implemented Stripe Embedded Checkout into the website. But somehow on new devices when they hit checkout Stripe Checkout page doesn't load just keeps showing loading and times out but if they attempt it second time it works just fine.
Is it a stripe issue or something which can be solved by making changes to flask file.
I havenot tried anything.

It will need a lot more details to debug. If you open browser console what do you see? What is the code you integrate the Stripe Embeded Checkout?
